# Export data with PHPexcel but got an error

Tags: codeigniter-3

The code where the error occurs:

This is my controller:

```
require (APPPATH.'libraries/PHPExcel.php');
        require (APPPATH.'libraries/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');


header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
            header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            //Nama File
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="report.xlsx"');
            //Download
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            $objWriter->save("php://output");
        }
    }
```

This is my error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class PHPExcel in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-sabusemusim\application\libraries\PHPExcel.php on line 35
```

Comment: what happen if you comment out : `require (APPPATH.'libraries/PHPExcel.php');` ?

Comment: can't be run or load..

Comment: what happen if you change `require` to `require_once`?

Comment: use require_once successfully, but it is now error on:  A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: controllers/Tb_report.php

Line Number: 3091

Backtrace:

Comment: this my controller : $x = $this->Tb_report->get_all();
    foreach ($x as $key => $data) { $objPHPexcell->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C10', $data['a']);
$objPHPexcell->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D10', $data['b']); }

Comment: Could you post a code in your question instead of in the comment, since it will be more readable

Comment: What is that `$data` variable contains? could you `var_dump()` it?

Comment: It turns out that there is an error in the model, in the array result function, now it's running, thanks